# What are the values for "Full Name" "First Name" and "Last Name" as they are entered into the props array for setting?

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, fuel-sdk, fuel, userrecordaccess

I'm trying to build a custom opt out page. The page will have a form to update the user's profile information. My code looks like this:

```
function updateUser($idNum, $userEmail, $fullName, $firstName, $lastName){  
    $myclient = new ET_Client();                    //required by the Fuel SDK
    $subscriber = new ET_Subscriber();              //Creates new subscriber object
    $subscriber->authStub = $myclient;              //passes necessary authentication for Exacttarget App
    $subscriber->props = array("EmailAddress" => $userEmail, "FullName" => $fullName, "First Name" => $firstName, "Last Name" => $lastName, "ID" => $idNum);//$subscriber->props = array("Email Address" => $userEmail, "Full Name" => $fullName, "First Name" => $firstName, "Last Name" => $lastName, "ID" => $idNum);    //Prepares the properties to be set for the ID.  , "FullName" => $fullName, "FirstName" => $firstName, "LastName" => $lastName,
    $results = $subscriber->patch();    
}
```

When this function runs, the profile with the ID parameter should be updated to have all the other parameters as values. The problem is that currently only the Email Address updates appropriately.

What is the correct call for the Patch function for "Full Name", "First Name" and "Last Name"? Do they have spaces in between or are they like "EmailAddress" without the space?

The reason why I'm asking this question is because the documentation doesn't specify how to call these attributes using the Fuel SDK which is what I am working in. And when I run this function, my proxy tells me that I'm getting a 401 error somewhere but the email address is still updating. The email updates but nothing else. Can someone help? I'm sure it's a simple fix.

Comment: The main reason the documentation doesn't list profile attributes out is that they can be virtually anything.  Some accounts might use `FName` and `LName`, or perhaps `First_Name` and `Last_Name`.  It should work based on what you have in your account.

Comment: What about updating the Attributes array instead of trying to call them specifically? How does the Fuel SDK update the attributes array?